# What is the backend of the mobiledata service of Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I analyzing if I use or not the mobiledata of Bluemix to my app, but I could not find what is the DB engine behind its Solution.
Anyone know what is the backend of mobiledata service of Bluemix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backend of mobile data service of bluemix is cloudant.For details please refer below link on getting started:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-rapiddev-app/

Answer (score 2):

Backend of mobile data service of bluemix uses Cloudant NoSQL Database for Bluemix as datastore.

Answer (score 1):

It actually uses Cloudant behind the scenes.  Cloudant is based on CouchDB and adds Lucene Indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can select any database service available on Bluemix to store your data. It depends on type of application and data to be stored. If you need to store relational data, go for a SQLDB service. If your mobile application need to store JSON data, then you need a NoSQL database service available on Bluemix. Cloudant is a good NoSQL database and most developers use it as a mobile data backend service.